# How can I save an XNA texture as a PNG file?

Tags: xna, png

I have a `Color[,]` variable and I already know how to convert it to a `Texture2D`. How do I then save it as `.png` image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.saveaspng.aspx)

```
public void SaveAsPng (
         Stream stream,
         int width,
         int height
)
```

Did you try:

```
// myTexture = something
Stream stream = File.Create("file.png"); 
myTexture.SaveAsPng( stream, myTexture.Width, myTexture.Height );
stream.Dispose();
myTexture.Dispose();
```